# Is there a way to download a google slides document of which I have view perms and I just have the link?

Tags: pdf, download, google-slides

This is the google slides document in question: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQCYjdh1xx8HY-rP_D33zlJ-DR9s5knPDbBXPUAZJoLCT8Sb5Iwr56MZXhnodGfYSYx1xfXr8jaCvem/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.p

I'm at the start of my year studying again, and I wanted to download these notes...is there way to achieve this? I tried to save page but that obviously won't work, it's an html, I want the original file to save it to my pc.

Is there maybe any web I can paste the link and get the file?

*PS: If this is not the appropriate subforum, please tell me where I could post the issue in the stack exchange forums. Thanks!*

Comment: @KJ so basically what you are saying is that there is no way to download by just having the link to the google slides doc?

Comment: @KJ yes that's what a colleague did, basically screen capture every slide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The publish link is a view-only Presesntation mode copy of the Google Slide file, and making a copy from this is disallowed. This is by design and can not be changed.*

#### More Information:

From the [help article](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) on publishing Workspace files:

> If you send someone the URL of a published file, they’ll see a version they can’t edit that looks different from yours. Here’s what others will see:
>
> **Presentations**: A view-only version or a version in presentation mode with full-screen slides.

And from the Publish dialog:

> Make your content visible to anyone by publishing it to the web. You can link to or embed your document. [Learn more](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=183965)

Note: the wording here is `view-only` and `visible`, which is not the same as `read-only`, which would include file copying.

If you wish to obtain a copy of the presentation, I suggest contacting the owner of the file.